# Setup for accessing an external SQL database from SP 2010 using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, 2010

I want to try to access an external SQL Server 2012 database on a SharePoint 2010 site, using javascript. I found one really interesting, good blog post about it online, but the link to the example code was missing. Drat.

Another example I found relied heavily on the Business Data Connectivity services... but that does not seem to be available on this site. Drat, too.

Does anyone know of a good book or site for what I propose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript to retrieve the database value is not a good practise. The best way is to use WebServices and use can retrieve the value through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using SharePoint designer and creating a datasource that connects to the database and then create a dataview based off that part.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558778(v=office.14).aspx